# Sum values in second column in a text file

Tags: perl, multiple-columns, text-processing

I have a text file with the following format:

```
1 4730 1031782 init
4 0 6 events
2190 450 0 top
21413 5928 1 sshd
22355 1970 2009 find
```

I need to sum the second column of data and return that value to the user.

My current attempt reads the data from the text file like so:

```
sub read_file{
  my $data_failed = 1;
  my $file = 'task_file';
  if (-z $file){print "No tasks found\n";}
  if(open (INFILE, "task_file" || die "$!\n")){
    my @COLUMNS = qw( memory cpu program );
    my %sort_strings = ( program => sub { $a cmp $b } );

    my (%process_details, %sort);

    while (<INFILE>) {
      $data_failed = 0;
      my ($process_id, $memory_size, $cpu_time, $program_name) = split;
      $process_details{$process_id} = { memory  => $memory_size,
                                        cpu     => $cpu_time,
                                        program => $program_name };
      undef $sort{memory}{$memory_size}{$process_id};
      undef $sort{cpu}{$cpu_time}{$process_id};
      undef $sort{program}{$program_name}{$process_id};
    }

    for my $column ($COLUMNS[2]) {
      my $cmp = $sort_strings{$column} || sub { $a <=> $b };
      for my $value (sort $cmp keys %{ $sort{$column} }
      ) {
          my @pids = keys %{ $sort{$column}{$value} };
          say join ' ', $_, @{ $process_details{$_} }{@COLUMNS}
              for @pids;
      }
  }
  if($total_memory_size == 1){
    sum_memory_size();
  }
} else { print "No tasks found"}
}
```

And my attempt to sum the values:

```
sub sum_memory_size{
  my @do_sum = qw(memory_size);

my $column;
my $value;

for $column (keys %{ $sort{$column}{$value} }) {
    my $found;
    my $sum = 0;
    for $value (@do_sum) {
        next unless exists $sort{$column}{$value};
        $sum += $hash{$column}{$value};
        delete $hash{$column}{$value};
        $found = 1;
    }
    $sort{$column}{somename} = $sum if $found;
}

print $sum;
}
```

Comment: Don't use `DATA` for a real filehandle, it's a special one (see [perldata](http://p3rl.org/perldata)).

Comment: Ok I am now using INFILE

Comment: It's better to use lexical filehandles rather than bareword ones.

Comment: `open (INFILE, "task_file" || die "$!\n")` That `||` is in the wrong place. Probably shouldn't be there at all if you keep testing the `open` in an `if`, actually. And the 3 argument version and lexical file handle like already mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sum` form [List::Util](http://p3rl.org/List::Util):

```
use List::Util qw{ sum };

# ...

my $memory_sum = sum(map $_->{memory}, values %process_details);
```

Comment: I am unfortunately unable to use any non-core functionality, is there a way of doing this with the `+` operator?

Comment: @DavideLorino `List::Util` has been in core since Perl 5.7.3 :)

Comment: @DavideLorino The sum function (available from any version of List::Util) can be easily replicated by the addition operator and a loop: `my $memory_sum = 0; $memory_sum += $_->{memory} for values %process_details;`

Answer (score 1):

The question describes a simple task, which appears to be part of a larger problem.  One answer to the simple task is:

```
perl -ne '@fields=split; $sum+=$fields[1]; END { print "$sum\n" }' foo.txt
```

For each line (`-ne`), split it and add the second value (`$fields[1]`) to a running `$sum`.  Then, after all lines have been processed (`END`), print the sum.  I get `13078` from the program, which is also what I get from a calculator on the input above :) (`4730 + 0 + 450 + 5928 + 1970`).

Comment: Thank you, how can I integrate this approach into a script without using a command line argument?